# Error posting JSON to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a set of json data to post to `create.php` and insert a record into mysql db.

The problem now is whenever i use ARC to post a json string, it give me this error

> There was an error parsing JSON data
>
> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

here is my json string

```
{"name": "clemen",
"price": 2213,
"description": "lee",
"category_id": "A111"}
```

here is my create.php code

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../objects/product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new Product($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$product->name = $data->name;
$product->price = $data->price;
$product->description = $data->description;
$product->category_id = $data->category_id;
$product->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// create the product
if($product->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Product was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create product."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

and i have create() function in my

**product.php**

```
// create product
function create(){

    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name=:name, price=:price, description=:description, category_id=:category_id, created=:created";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->price=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));
    $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->category_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
    $this->created=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->created));

    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":price", $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $this->category_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":created", $this->created);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Please describe full error message with line number: Not just this unexpected token message

Comment: That error is an indication from php, it's saying that there's something else being printed before the json, I would debug the db connection.

Comment: Why don't you grab your json post at top of your file then?

Comment: First, how is this data being submitted? Also, have you tried printing the file_get_contents output?